# many-to-many relationships in sequelize can't use include?

Tags: express, sequelize.js

So I have a project in which a User can join a Weekly Ladder so I made a belongsToMany relationship between both fields through a third model called UserLadder where I also added an extra field that keeps track of the user points at this ladder.

Basically now in my express app I need a route to shop users and their points by tournament so I wrote this:

```
 const leaderboard = await UserLadder.findAll({
   where: {
     weeklyLadderId: req.params.id,
   },
   limit: req.params.playersNumber,
   order: [['userPoints', 'DESC']],
 });

 res.json(leaderboard);
```

and it worked in the sense of it did show me everyone in this tournament and ordered them according to their points but problem was that the user showed just as a userId field and I wanted to eager load that using Include but it says that there's no relation between the user model and the userladder model.

the temporary solution I did was:

```
const ladder = await WeeklyLadder.findByPk(req.params.id);
const users = await ladder.getUsers({
  attributes: ['displayName'],
});
res.json(users);
```

which I got the tournament by Id and then got there users of the tournament but this is a 2 step process and I know there's a way to do it through the third UserLadder model I just cant figure it out

any ideas?

accosiations:

```
const User = require('./models/User');
const WeeklyLadder = require('./models/WeeklyLadder');
const Game = require('./models/Game');
const UserLadder = require('./models/UserLadder');

User.belongsToMany(WeeklyLadder, {
  through: UserLadder,
});

WeeklyLadder.belongsToMany(User, {
  through: UserLadder,
});

Game.hasMany(WeeklyLadder);

WeeklyLadder.belongsTo(Game);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute with just one request :

```
db.User.findOne({
    include: [
        {
            model: db.WeeklyLadder,
            as: "WeeklyLadder",
            where: {
                title: "tournament 1", // where on WeeklyLadder
            },
        },
    ],
})
```

On your models :

```
User.associate = (models) => {
    models.User.belongsToMany(models.WeeklyLadder, {
        as: "WeeklyLadder",
        through: "UserWeeklyLadder",
        foreignKey: "fk_user_id",
        otherKey: "fk_weekly_ladder_id",
    })
}

...

WeeklyLadder.associate = (models) => {
    models.WeeklyLadder.belongsToMany(models.User, {
        as: "User",
        through: "UserWeeklyLadder",
        foreignKey: "fk_weekly_ladder_id",
        otherKey: "fk_user_id",
    })
}
```

Comment: but this will bring me the one user with his ladder data, I want the data of all the users that are in this ladder not just one to show in a leaderboard!

Comment: if you want all users, remove the first where => where: {
        id: 1, // where on User (remove if your want all users)
    },

Comment: No, I do not think you understand my question correctly, I want all users that are in this one tournament/ladder I don't want all users in general and the tournaments they're in because there will be different tournaments, not just one. so if I queried the user this will just get me all users and the tournaments they're in not the reverse.

Comment: With this request, you will have all the users who participate in the tournaments with the title "tournaments1", not all users, just users linked with tournaments "tournaments1"

Comment: Hey, it actually worked sorry I was a little bit confused but if you don't mind I added a screenshot to the question that shows how the data came back and as you can see the "user_ladder" part of it which is the 3rd model is actually the one that has the points of the user in it, is there's a direct way to order by it or not?

Comment: Perfect @A.Atiyah ! I think it's an other question (thank you to validate this if the answer is correct and open a new question) but, it's always better to manipulate the data not using directly the linker table : I think it's better to use your model User or WeeklyLadder.